# Proxy and map for a graph database

Tags: database, dictionary, graph, proxy, graph-databases

I want to store a huge graph on several nodes. That is why I need a Map server which will know where each vertex is stored. It can be any database (Relational or NoSQL, doesn't matter) stores only one table with two columns like these:
vertex id | server_id
I don't want to use consistent hashing or something similar to store vertex because of traversal problems.
Also I need some proxy which will work with Map server and with graph databases (partitions).This proxy must accept requests from application (like "get Vertex by Id"), asks the Map server "where that vertex is stored" and then redirect request to correct node.
Here is example of architecture:
[image: Proxy and Map for graph databases]

Is there a proxy like this? Or maybe some solution or something else? Any graph database any proxy for that graph any ideas will be pleasurable.

Comment: Why don't you use a distributed graph database such as Titan with Cassandra or HBase if you want an on-premises solution. https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan.

Comment: Cassandra uses consistent hashing. This solution isn't fit well for a social graph database. If you will store users randomly then they will evenly spread among your nodes but you will lose the ability to optimize traversal among nodes. Imagine if you have a graph database spread among 50 nodes and you need to get 100 friends of a concrete user. This simple request can asks all nodes to get these users (or almost all nodes). It can affect latency too much. But if you optimize graph traversal you can get all friends from one or several (not many) nodes which will improve speed of requests.

Comment: Here is the post about facebook optimization: https://code.facebook.com/posts/274771932683700/large-scale-graph-partitioning-with-apache-giraph/

Comment: Objectivity/DB provides support for distributed graphs and it has a Placement Management Description framework that allows you to write rules for where new objects (nodes and edges) should be placed. It also supports edges between nodes on two different servers. Finally, it uses and Object id (OID) that allows it to determine which server a particular node or edge is on, no mapping server required. Objectivity/DB has what it call a Single Logical View of a massively scalable and distributed graph. Once the object is placed using the PMD layer, the API takes care of finding the data.